# System hangs while running a .cpp code using SURF algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, ros, surf

I am working on image processing using openCV and c++. I wrote a code using SURF algorithm for detecting the keypoints from an image and show the detected keypoints. I am able to build and run the code without any error. But the system hangs after running the code.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic and OpenCV 3.3.1 which was installed automatically with ROS.

I included all the necessary header files for using SURF algorithm and also used required 'namespaces'. The main file of my code is as follows:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc,argv,"image_detection");
while(1)
{
Mat temp_image=imread("/home/pelican/Pictures/sign.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat temp_kp;

//initialize SURF
Ptr<SURF>detector=SURF::create(500,4,4,false,false);

//compute keypoints
vector<KeyPoint>kp;
detector->detect(temp_image,kp);

//display keypoints
drawKeypoints(temp_image,kp,temp_kp,Scalar(255,0,150),DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
cout<<"detected kp="<<kp.size()<<endl;

namedWindow("template_image",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("template_image",temp_image);
namedWindow("temp_kp",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("temp_kp",temp_kp);

ros::spinOnce();
if(waitKey(30)==27) //wait for esc key press for 30ms. If pressed,break loop
{
cout<<"esc key pressed"<<endl;
break;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

I had edited the CMakeLists.txt and Package.xml file also. After that I followed the steps:

1. roscore
2. change the directory to catkin_ws and source it.
3. catkin_make
4. rosrun package_name node_name

When the code start running, the system hangs. So, I just try to build and run each steps. I came to know that the system works fine till `vector<KeyPoint>kp;`. But the system hangs if I include the step `detector->detect(temp_image,kp);`. If I try to run the whole code (above code), after 5-6 minutes, it will display the number of detected keypoints and the windows 'template_image' and 'temp_kp' with the image(sign.jpg), but not displaying the detected keypoints in 'temp_kp'. And finally I have to force restart the system using power button.

How can I fix this and what might be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the image and checking if this helps? A bit more detail about the image!

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rick for your reply. The code works fine without any delay when I changed my laptop.